# ASP.NET modify resource values from .resx files at runtime

Tags: asp.net, runtime, resx

My current requirements for the application that I am working on are that the client should be able to modify the texts used in the interface from a screen within the application itself.
These are of course saved in resx files.
Is there any way to do this?
Modify the values of the resources at runtime?
  What would be the easiest way?
Thank you in advance

Edit: resx files are already implemented and there are a lot of keys used all throughout the application

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is to edit label texts during runtime than I would suggest that you don't use RESX files, as them are ment to be static, but rather use database.

Comment: I would use database loosely in this context, depending on the number of users requiring the same interface text, it may be more efficient and simplier to have a XML file on a shared drive.

Comment: unfortunately resx files have already been implemented so if there is I way I could use them that would be great

Comment: Suppose there is disadvantage in meter of performances by using database instead of resx files?

Comment: @AndrejKaurin - Than I would say that you need to sort out your database first rather then switch to files lying on the hard drive. Also, think about scaling out: if you have two boxes, where will the resx file be?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) using a database as backend. This way your code doesn't change and you'll have the possibility to update text directly.